# Problem with UISPlitViewController toolbar

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad

I'm trying to use a toolbar in a splitviewcontroller. For some reasons that are unknown to me, the table view on the left is not resized correctly.

[image]

If I turn to portrait and open the table view from the toolbar item and then go back to landscape view, the tableview is then displayed properly. I'm not sure why this happens.

This is what I have in the RootViewController:

```
self.navigationController.toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:... nil]; // Setting these to an empty array doesn't change anything
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
self.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
```

I doubt the bug is there, but the complete source code is available on [github](https://github.com/oscardelben/GithubEditor) if there's something obvious to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved the code into viewDidAppear and it now works as expected.